# Interpretation of Bayes Formula Question

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

[image]

This is a simple application of Bayes Theorem, I'm just confused about the labeling. If i let T = test outcome is positive, D = patient has disease, then, I am trying to find

$$
P ( D | \bar{T} ) = \frac{P(D,\bar{T})}{P(\bar{T})}\\
=\frac{P(\bar{T}|D)P(D)}{P(\bar{T}|D)P(D)+P(\bar{T}|\bar{D})P(\bar{D})}\\
=\frac{0.25 \cdot 0.25}{0.25 \cdot 0.25 + 0.75 \cdot 0.75}
=0.1
$$

Is this the correct interpretation?

Comment: I concur with James.  I haven't checked your arithmetic, but it appears to be correct reasoning leading up to plugging in numbers.  A small typesetting note, I recommend \overline{} instead of \bar{} since the \bar{} makes a bar of a specific size that doesn't increase with the size of what the bar is going over.  E.g.: $\bar{\text{\bar}}~\overline{\text{\overline}}$

Comment: @JMoravitz I was more concerned with the interpretation of the statement though. As in, does the question imply that $P(\overline{T}|D) = 0.25 $ or am I understanding it incorrectly

Comment: Ah, well parsing the information in the question, "correctly gives a (true) positive is .75" corresponds to $P(T|D) = .75$.  "falsely gives an incorrect positive is .25" corresponds to $P(T|\overline{D})=.25$.  From these it follows that $P(\overline{T}|D) = 1-P(T|D) = .25$ and $P(\overline{T}|\overline{D}) = 1 - P(T|\overline{D}) = 1-.25 = .75$.  In general $P(A|B) = 1 - P(\overline{A}|B)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation of the numbers appears correct.  Your concern was over whether you correctly interpreted what $P(\overline{T}|D)$ was.  You may use and/or memorize the following result:

> $P(A|B) = 1 - P(\overline{A}|B)$

Proof:
$$\begin{align}
P(A|B) & = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)} & \text{by definition of conditional probability}\\
& = \frac{P(A\cap B) + P(\overline{A}\cap B) - P(\overline{A}\cap B)}{P(B)} & \text{by adding "zero"}\\
& = \frac{P((A\cap B)\cup(\overline{A}\cap B)) - P(\overline{A}\cap B)}{P(B)}& \text{since}~A\cap B~\text{is disjoint from}~\overline{A}\cap B\\
&=\frac{P((A\cup \overline{A})\cap B) - P(\overline{A}\cap B)}{P(B)} &\text{by distributivity}\\
&=\frac{P(S\cap B) - P(\overline{A}\cap B)}{P(B)} & \text{by definition of compliments}\\
&=\frac{P(B) - P(\overline{A}\cap B)}{P(B)} & \text{by definition of sample space}\\
&=\frac{P(B)}{P(B)} - \frac{P(\overline{A}\cap B)}{P(B)}&\text{by algebra}\\
&=1 - P(\overline{A}|B) & \text{by definition of conditional probability}\end{align}$$